# Python-How to create a list of N elements from a given list

Tags: python, list

I need to create a list of size N from already given list.

```
N = 3
a_list = [10,4,18,2,6,19,24,1,20]
```

The O/P should be:

```
[10,4,18] [4,18,2] [18,2,6] [2,6,19] [6,19,24] [19,24,1] [24,1,20]
```

It's like a window size of N=3 , which slides one step to its right.

How will I do it?

Comment: no, that will be to get `[10,4,18],[2,6,19],[24,1,20]`

Comment: @alko - I checked this thread already. But the problem was different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A faster way:

```
>>> zip(a_list,a_list[1:],a_list[2:])
[(10, 4, 18), (4, 18, 2), (18, 2, 6), (2, 6, 19), (6, 19, 24), (19, 24, 1), (24, 1, 20)]
```

Comparison:

```
In [6]: %timeit [a_list[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(a_list)-n+1)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.61 us per loop

In [7]: %timeit zip(a_list,a_list[1:],a_list[2:])
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.23 us per loop
```

Or more general:

```
>>> zip(*[a_list[i:] for i in range(3)]) #3 (or 2, 4, 5, etc)is the length of step
```

For larger `list`, probably you have to use `numpy` to get a faster solution than @Ashwini Chaudhary's (http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html):

```
import numpy as np
lista=np.array(lis)
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

%timeit [lis[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(lis)-n+1)] 
%timeit rolling_window(lista, n)

1 loops, best of 3: 171 ms per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: Please explain. how will `zip(*[a_list[i:] for i in range(3)])` be valid for n=5

Comment: Oh, change `3` to any number, like `5`. That is essentially `zip(a_list,a_list[1:],a_list[2:],.....)`

Comment: Now I've a string in my file as `10 4 18 2 6 19 24 1 20` . I'm able to read that string but how should I convert this 'Line' to an List?

Comment: What I'm doing is `list((f1.readline()).replace(" ",""))`. it returns me `['1', '0', '4', '1', '8', '2', '6', '1', '9', '2', '4', '1', '2', '0', '\n']`

Comment: how about `map(int,s[:-1].split(' '))`, `s` is your line `10 4 18 2 6 19 24 1 20\n`, because when you `readline()` there is a `\n` in the end.

Comment: Please check my solution. Is it the optimized version? or is there any better solution than this.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417925/python-algorithmic-statement Thanks

Comment: Fast only for this particular case, try it with bigger list and it is 6-7 times slower.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary. That's interesting. Can't keep wondering about why it is so. For large dimension, probably there is no better way than yours except using `numpy`, see edit. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Use list comprehension and slicing:

```
>>> lis = [10,4,18,2,6,19,24,1,20]
>>> n = 3
>>> [lis[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(lis)-n+1)]
[[10, 4, 18], [4, 18, 2], [18, 2, 6], [2, 6, 19], [6, 19, 24], [19, 24, 1], [24, 1, 20]]
>>> n = 4
>>> [lis[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(lis)-n+1)]
[[10, 4, 18, 2], [4, 18, 2, 6], [18, 2, 6, 19], [2, 6, 19, 24], [6, 19, 24, 1], [19, 24, 1, 20]]
```

For a bigger list the `zip` based approach is actually slower:

```
In [27]: n = 100                                                                                 

In [28]: lis = [10,4,18,2,6,19,24,1,20]*10000                                                    

In [30]: %timeit zip(*[lis[i:] for i in xrange(n)])                                              
1 loops, best of 3: 593 ms per loop                                                              

In [31]: %timeit [lis[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(lis)-n+1)]                                      
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop
```

Comment: Dang, i was slightly late. +1 sir.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually also actually thinking of using slicing, but was not clear on my thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Now I've a string in my file as `10 4 18 2 6 19 24 1 20` . I'm able to read that string but how should I convert this 'Line' to an List?

Comment: What I'm doing is `list((f1.readline()).replace(" ",""))`. it returns me `['1', '0', '4', '1', '8', '2', '6', '1', '9', '2', '4', '1', '2', '0', '\n']`

Comment: @user1162512 `lis = '10 4 18 2 6 19 24 1 20'.split()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
>>> lis = [10,4,18,2,6,19,24,1,20]
>>> n=3
>>> [lis[i:i+n] for i in range(len(lis))][:-2]
```

the output is

```
[[10, 4, 18], [4, 18, 2], [18, 2, 6], [2, 6, 19], [6, 19, 24], [19, 24, 1], [24, 1, 20]]
```