# Python- Algorithmic statement

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to write a program which does the follows : -

**Sample Input:**

```
3
10 4 18 2 6 19 24 1 20
```

**Expected Output:**

```
4 2 2 2 6 1 1
```

The input will from a file in which the first line will contain the window size N, the second line will contain a stream of numbers separated by space. You need to output the smallest numbers in each window separated by space.

This is what I wrote:-

```
with open ("file") as f1:
    n = int(f1.readline())
    numbers = f1.readline()

# converting the string of numbers into a list
numbers_list = map(int,numbers[:-1].split(' ')) 

# getting all the sub-lists of size n from the numbers_list and printing their respective minimum elements.
print [min(numbers_list[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(numbers_list)-n+1)]
```

**My o/p**

```
[4, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1, 1]
```

Is there some better solution than this? Any optimized version of this solution.

Comment: `numbers = map(int, f1.readline().split())`

Comment: Yes, that's an improvisation. Thanks. Any more suggestions please

Comment: I generally prefer `next(f1)` to `f1.readline()`...

Comment: Why? Is it because of the personal preference or is it better in terms of performance?

Comment: @user1162512 Just some ideas to put in your back pocket: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization.

Comment: Ya Ya Ya I've read this. but I still need to master the optimization. Thanks Anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(min, [nums[x:x+window] for x in xrange(len(nums)-(window-1))])
```

However, this creates an intermediate list, so:

```
[min(nums[x:x+window]) for x in xrange(len(nums)-(window+1))]
```

is actually better, which is what you currently have.

There is a more time efficient way, however, it would be more code.  Once you have the min-value for a window, all you're doing is looking at the next slot, so all you need to do is compare the min value from the previous (window-1) elements to the next value.  Whichever is smaller will be the next number in your results list. Repeat.

For example, if you have a four element list and your window is size 3. The first value in your results list will be the minimum of the first three elements, and the second value in your results list will be the minimum of the last three elements.

There's a two element overlap there. So you can save the minimum value of the last window-1 elements and compare that to the next value in the list to get the min value for the next window. Repeat.

With respect to the file handling,

```
with open ("file") as f1:
    n = int(f1.readline())
    numbers_list = map(int, f1.readline().split(' '))
```

is slightly more efficient.

Comment: Please explain how using lambda is better? Thanks

Comment: @FMc - So, what I'm doing is it the best solution? Or can I improvise on it further?

Comment: @user1162512 Didn't realize this is what you did, lol...This seems fine.

Comment: I don't really see how this is much better than OP's solution.  It looks pretty much the same.

Comment: @mgilson It's worse, in fact.  I made an addendum.

Comment: @user1162512 I made an edit, there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @user1162512 No problem.  Again, not sure if it's worth it, though. If you actually need something to go fast, and the window size can be large, then it probably is...

Comment: But I think you misunderstood my question. I need to get the minimum value from each window. Hence there is no need to compare the min value with the previous min. value.

Comment: @user1162512 If you have a four element list and your window is size 3.  The first value in your results list will be the minimum of the first three elements, and the second value in your results list will be the minimum of the last three elements.  There's a two element overlap there.  So you can save the minimum value of the last window-1 elements and compare that to the next value in the list to get the min value for the next window.

Comment: Ohh. Yeah...you are correct. Can you please provide e a demo of that. I want to have a look at that one as well. Thanks

Comment: @user1162512 Tbh, I'm really busy and at this point in time just randomly go on SO when I'm procrastinating, but I need to get back to work.  If I find free time, I'll code it up, but that's not too likely.  It's not too difficult, though.  It would be more beneficial to you to code it up yourself.  Usually for these types of problems, I prefer to give solutions in an algorithmic sense and let the OP code from there.  Hint you're probably going to need to keep track of two values...

Comment: Ok. I'll try it myself and will notify you by posting the solution over here. If you find some time, please review it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here's some kind of optimization. Main idea is not to scan window for each index, but to maintain a sorted double ended queue ([`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)), let's call it `q`, and remove unneseccary elements while traversing through original list. This queue remains sorted while traversing, so first element is always minimum, see algorithm below:

#### Algorithm:

- **Initilize** `q` with indexes of sorted first `w` (window length) elements of list, in OP case this would be `[1, 0, 2]` (because first 3 elements sorted are `[4, 10, 18]`, so we just need to take indexes of these elements). I've used [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for this task.
- Remove all indexes which are **less then index of minimum element** of `q` (we don't need it, because elements with these indexes can't be mins in any new window). So now we have `[1, 2]`.
- Now **iterate** over remaining indexes, for each index:

  - Remove indexes from the **left end** of `q` if it's not in current window (so we get rid of previous minimum elements if they are outside of the current window).
  - Remove indexes from the **right end** of `q` if elements on these indexes are greater that element with current index.
  - Add `q[0]` to resulting list `res` of indexes.
- **Return** elements with indexes from `res`.

Note that each element added and removed from the `q` only once, so amortized complexity is **`O(N)`** where `N` is size of initial array/list. The simple algorithm counting min for each window would be **`O(NW)`** where `W` is window size.

#### Code:

```
def rolling_min(nums, w):
    n = np.argsort(nums[:w])
    q = deque(x for x in n if x >= n[0])
    res = [q[0]]
    for i in xrange(w, len(nums)):
        while len(q) > 0 and q[0] <= i - w:
            q.popleft()
        while len(q) > 0 and nums[q[-1]] > nums[i]:
            q.pop()
        q.append(i)
        res.append(q[0])
    return [nums[i] for i in res]
```

#### Tests:

May be my code could be optimized even further, here's some tests, my code works 10 times slower than simple list comprehension on OP data, but it works 10 times faster on larger list and larger window:

```
>>> def rolling_min1(nums, w):
...     return [min(nums[x:x + w]) for x in xrange(len(nums) - (w - 1))]
>>> rolling_min2 = rolling_min

# OP data, small list, small window
>>> nums = numbers_list
>>> w = 3
>>> timeit('r = rolling_min1(nums, w)', 'from __main__ import nums, w, rolling_min1', number=100)
0.0005016330251237378
>>> timeit('r = rolling_min2(nums, w)', 'from __main__ import nums, w, rolling_min2', number=100)
0.004806720447959378

# Large list, large window
>>> nums = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000)
>>> w = 100
>>> timeit('r = rolling_min1(nums, w)', 'from __main__ import nums, w, rolling_min1', number=100)
13.711818511466845
>>> timeit('r = rolling_min2(nums, w)', 'from __main__ import nums, w, rolling_min2', number=100)
1.3878068031772273
```